# Select multiple files (different files from different directory) with 1 input type file element.

Tags: html

i know that we can add a multiple attribute, but this only allows me to select several files at a time in the same directory in browser.

im wondering if it is possible to select multiple files from different directory for the same input file type element **using html only.** thanks in advance.

Comment: this is the kind of question you ask on google not here on SO

Comment: From different directories? You mean open multiple upload dialogs?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible using only HTML and definitely not with only one input type="file".

Here is what the HTML form could look like, but **note** this alone is not enough.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select files: <br/>
<input type='file' name='files0[]' id="files0" multiple><br/><br/><br/>
<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Click "+" for more files
<i id="more_files" class="general foundicon-plus" style="color: blue;cursor: pointer;"></i></span>
<br/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Using jQuery/Javascript you can add an onclick event to the "+" that generates a new input type="file" to the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#more_files', function() {
        var numOfInputs = 1;
        while($('#files'+numOfInputs).length) { numOfInputs++; }//once this loop breaks, numOfInputs is greater than the # of browse buttons

        $("<input type='file' multiple/>")
            .attr("id", "files"+numOfInputs)
            .attr("name", "files"+numOfInputs+"[]")
            .insertAfter("#files"+(numOfInputs-1));

        $("<br/>").insertBefore("#files"+numOfInputs);
    });
});
</script>
```

Lastly, with PHP you can wrap the data in a familiar format with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES)) {
    $files = array();
    $files = $_FILES['files0'];
    //var_dump($files);//this array will match the structure of $_FILES['browser']
    //Iterate through each browser button
    $browserIterator = 1;
    while(isset($_FILES['files'.$browserIterator])) {
        //Files have same attribute structure, so grab each attribute and append data for each attribute from each file
        foreach($_FILES['files'.$browserIterator] as $attr => $values) {//get each attribute
            foreach($_FILES['files'.$browserIterator][$attr] as $fileValue)     {//get each value from attribute
                $files[$attr][] = $fileValue;//append value
            }
        }
        $browserIterator++;
    }
    //Use $files like you would use $_FILES['browser'] -- It is as though all files came from one browser button!
    $fileIterator = 0;
    while($fileIterator < count($files['name'])) {
        echo $files['name'][$fileIterator]."<br/>";
        $fileIterator++;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using more than one `<input type="file" />` element for your form is the best you can do. It's not possible to select multiple files from different directories in a single upload dialog.